# Rails 4 - Helper not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, helper

I am on Rails 4 trying to build a simple helper to reduce some of the code in my view.

Here is the view code (show.html.erb) before using a helper:

```
<% unless @article.long_effects.blank? %>
  <ul>
    <% @article.long_effects.split(';').each do |effect| %>
      <li><%= effect %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

and here is the helper I built for the above code:

```
def list(attribute)
  unless attribute.blank?
    content_tag(:ul) do
      attribute.split(';').each do |a|
        content_tag(:li, a)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which I then call from the view like so

```
<%= list(@article.long_effects) %>
```

Unfortunately, the helper is not returning anything. This is my first time writing a helper that returns HTML, so maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from

```
def list(attribute)
  unless attribute.blank?
    content_tag(:ul) do
      attribute.split(';').each do |a|
        content_tag(:li, a)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

to

```
def list(attribute)
  unless attribute.blank?
    content_tag(:ul) do
      attribute.split(';').each do |a|
        concat content_tag(:li, a)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`concat` method will be useful to join the collection object from looping conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you able to explain the concat a bit more? Confused as to why this makes it work. @richfisher

Comment: the code block `attribute.split(';').each { |a| # do something }` return `attribute.split(';')`, so you need to concat the content in the loop manually.